# Getting Multiple Sql commands operated in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to get a divided count value for a specific name as follows

```
var query = "select round((cast(x.num as float) / cast(y.num as float)*100),0) as Q from (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution  where Name = '" + data.K + "' and Visits ='" +
                            c +
                            "') x join (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution where Name = '" + data.K + "' ) y on 1=1 ";
```

What I want to do is execute the following command in the same method

```
var query = "select round((cast(x.num as float) / cast(y.num as float)*100),0) as Q from (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution  where Name = '" + data.C + "' and Visits ='" +
                            c +
                            "') x join (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution where Name = '" + data.C + "' ) y on 1=1 ";
```

I need to get the values from these queries to separate columns using angular js. I can do that but the problem is I can't execute these 2 queries at the same time and add the resulting values to the respective columns to a list.

Comment: They look very similar. Why not joining them in one statement? For example with Union or with a View?

Comment: the queries are different from where clause. I need the count separately for data.K and data.C. after that I need to add them to a list under separate column names. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var query = "select round((cast(x.num as float) / cast(CASE WHEN y.num = 0 THEN 1 ELSE y.num END as float)*100),0) as Q, round((cast(a.num as float) / cast(CASE WHEN b.num = 0 THEN 1 ELSE b.num END as float)*100),0) as R from 
                (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution  where Name = '" + data.K + "' and Visits ='" + c + "' ) x 
                join (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution where Name = '" + data.K + "' ) y on 1=1
                join (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution  where Name = '" + data.C + "' and Visits ='" + c + "' ) a on 1=1
                join (select count(*) as num from VisitDistribution where Name = '" + data.C + "' ) b on 1=1"
```

Comment: check for zero and replace with one. Use `Case When` syntax. I added to the statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this using CROSS JOIN

```
SELECT T1.Columns1 , T2.Columns2   FROM TABLE1 AS T1  CROSS JOIN  TABLE2 AS T2
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to try this. The first column provides value for data.K and the second column does to the data.C.

```
"Select SUM( case when Z.Name = data.K then Z.Q else 0 end) K,
SUM( case when Z.Name = data.C then Z.Q else 0 end) C

(select X.Name, 

round((cast(X.num as float)/cast(y.num as float)*100,0) as Q

from (select X.Name,count(*) as num from VisitDistribution where Name
IN (' + data.K + "','" + data.C + "') and Visits ='" + c +
"' group by Name) x join (Y.Name,select count(*) as num from 
VisitDistribution where Name IN (' + data.K + "','" + data.C + "' Group by 
Name) y on x.Name = Y.Name) Z";
```

Hope this help!

thanks,
Venkatesh

Comment: Venkatesh welcome to SO.please format your code using {} in editor